# TanStack Table 8 : access nested array in data model

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to access a nested array in my data structure.
My objects in my data array look like this :

```
{
name: name,
logo: url,
categories: [
  {
    name: Entertainment,
    slug: "entertainment
  },
  {
    name: Kids,
    slug: kids
  },
]
}
```

In the [Docs](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/guide/column-defs) I states that I need to use `columnHelper.accessor` to extract primitive values for each item in your data array.
My question is : how can I configure my accessor on "categories" to display both of them in my cell (using map I guess) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't *need* to use `columnHelper`; you can, for convenience (well, type safety, mostly).

You can do something like this:

```
cell: info => { 
  const value = info.getValue() as YourCategoryType[]; //casting may not be required here
  return <>{value.map(v => <p key={v.slug}>{v.name}</p>)}</>
},
```